# Using z-index to layer a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6VGy4/

I am using hover to display the grey background, however whatever `z-index` I use, the `.navbar` is never above the `.bt`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple, just add `position: relative;` to `.navbar`

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/6VGy4/1/

You need to establish **"stacking context"**, one of the ways is positioning and assigning a `z-index` value. The positioning needs to be done absolutely or relatively, and it has to be declared ***explicitly***, even tough by default it is `relative`, you still need to declare it.